# Vim python backend, how to import user installed shared libraries?

Tags: vimscript-python

I (very) often write python, and I use Vim's python3 backend to test my code.  To perform my tests I use:

```
vnoremap <localleader>p y:<c-r>"<c-b>python3 <cr>
```

It simply takes my visual selection and runs within Vim's python backend.  This is very practical because I can re-run only pieces of code (and I'm careful to remember the state the repl is in).

This works fine even with installed libraries, for example [`beautifulsoup4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) works:

```
:python3 import bs4
```

But my issue starts when I try loading libraries that are not fully written in python.  For example trying [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
:python3 import numpy
```

I get an error from the backend:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/grochmal/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/grochmal/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/grochmal/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/grochmal/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/grochmal/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /home/grochmal/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefine
d symbol: PyType_GenericNew
```

After debugging it a good deal I got to the conclusion that the issue only happens in `/home/grochmal/.local` and only to libraries that have components compiled from C.  In other words, if I install `numpy` into `/usr/lib` it works.

#### The question

The python REPL has no issue with libraries at `~/.local` but Vim's python backend does.  I tried with and without:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/grochmal/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

And the issue persists.  Is there a way to use locally installed shared libraries together with Vim's python backend?  i.e. Can I tell Vim's python backend to search both places (`/usr/lib` and `~/.local`) for symbols to load?

---

<sub>Extra note: both `bs4` and `numpy` are in `~/.local` in the tests above.  In other words libraries that are fully written in python do work in `~/.local`</sub>

Comment: PS: I do use `makeprg=python3\ %`, but that is just too slow when huge libraries are being loaded or a lot of data is read from files.  Yes, i'm using Vim like an ide, shame on me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your numpy isn't linked against the Python 3 library (no `-lpython3` used). This is fine for most applications that has the library loaded into global space, but Vim uses `RTLD_LOCAL` so numpy's libraries don't see Python 3's symbols unless it's linked against it.

`LD_PRELOAD` is fine as long as you don't load Python 2 in the same Vim (or symbols may clash; that's why Vim doesn't use `RTLD_GLOBAL`). You can also recompile your numpy with `-lpython3` (from Arch's PKGBUILD it seems that `export LDFLAGS=-shared` is enough to do that).

Comment: Whelp, yeah.  I was almost there, but not quite.  Tested it (recompiled my numpy with `-lpython3`) and it works.  p2k cannot go away soon enough (I know that people are saying that for 5 years already and will probably not happen in the next 5 either).  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround

After a good deal of debugging I found that forcing Vim to have the shared library in memory all the time sorts the problem.  i.e.

```
alias vim='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libpython3.so vim'
```

Yes, it is horrible, but works on most systems (tested on CentOS, Debian and Arch).  Another problem is that `LD_PRELOAD` is Linux specific.

After this I can load a `numpy` library from `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` with `:python3 import numpy`.

---

#### Extra info

I'm still baffled at the issue since in Vim code the library should come from:

```
src/option.h: EXTERN char_u *p_py3dll;  /* 'pythonthreedll' */
```

Which in turn should come from `-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL`, which should be a static makefile argument.  Therefore, I believe that the issue lies somewhere in (`src/if_python3.c`):

```
# ifndef WIN3264
#  include <dlfcn.h>
#  define FARPROC void*
#  define HINSTANCE void*
#  if defined(PY_NO_RTLD_GLOBAL) && defined(PY3_NO_RTLD_GLOBAL)
#   define load_dll(n) dlopen((n), RTLD_LAZY)
#  else
#   define load_dll(n) dlopen((n), RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL)
#  endif
...
```

And that `RTLD_LOCAL` (i.e. no `RTLD_GLOBAL`) is possibly used.  But I never used `dlopen()` and may be completely wrong about this.